# Re-group sublist element by a reference list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list filled with a large number of elements, eg. {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

I wanna partition the list by a reference list. The reference list shows how those elements need to be grouped. eg. {{1,3},{4,6},{7,2,5},{9,10,11}...}. The reference list also contains the unwanted element/sublist.

My current methods are:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
reflist = {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 2, 5}, {9, 10, 11}};

Flatten[DeleteDuplicates[
  Table[Select[reflist, MemberQ[#, list1[[i]]] &], {i, 1, 
    Length@list1}]], 1]
```

This methods works but is not efficient. my list1 could be more than half-million unique elements. I am seeking a more effective way to do it.

Comment: Is this more efficient? `Select[reflist, Length@Intersection[list1, #] > 0 &]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select[reflist, ContainsAll[list1, #] &]
```

> {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 2, 5}}

Comment: The 8 shouldn't be there, it's not in list1.

Comment: @flinty The output is the same with [op ask](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261595/re-group-sublist-element-by-a-reference-list/261596#:~:text=This%20methods%20works%20but%20is%20not%20efficient)

Comment: yeah that confused me: it says _"partition the list by a reference list"_ so why would the list1 which does not contain an 8 get partitioned into a list-of-lists which does?

Comment: @flinty By the name, he should be a Chinese. Not very good at expressing in English. But my results are the same as his.

Comment: Sorry, I have made some mistakes typing. It has been corrected.

Comment: @YubaoDeng Frankly, I still don't know what you want

Comment: @yode thank you for your answer. Your code is exactly what I want.

Comment: Try: list1[[#]] & /@ Most@reflist

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[{___, Alternatives @@ list1 , ___}] @ reflist
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 2, 5}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 2, 5}, {9, 10, 11}};

e = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Using `Cases` and `SubsetQ`

```
Cases[list, x_ /; SubsetQ[e, x]]
```

{{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 2, 5}}

Using `Pick` and `ContainsAll`

```
Pick[list, ContainsAll[e, #] & /@ list]
```

{{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 2, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
reflist = {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 2, 5}, {9, 10, 11}};
```

---

Using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[reflist, x_ /; FreeQ[UniqueElements[{list1, x}], {}]]

(*{{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 2, 5}}*)
```